# Eclipse Glassfish 4.0 Unable to start server on time

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, kepler

I fight with glassfish on eclipse through 2 days and I still can't run my server. When I try to start my server, (loading) progress bar hangs on 69% and obtain message like:
**Unable to start server on time**
**java.util.concurrent.timeoutexception**

Server does something like that:
1. **[Starting, synchronized]** (btw. in web browser server works only for few seconds but still doesn't see index.html. It displays default page of GlassFish server with message **Your server is now running** and then localhost doesn't want to respond anymore)
2. **[Stopped]**

and I can't achieve state of server: **[Started, synchronized]**
Btw. I was using Tomcat Server and i hadn't issues to start it.

I have:
**Windows 7 x64**
**Eclipse Kepler**
**JDK 1.8**
**JRE 1.8**
**GlassFish 4.0** - which I downloaded using Eclipse

and here are logs from console:

```html
Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 60ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8�080]
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8�181]
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4�848]
Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3�700]
Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (1�824ms), startup services(940ms), total(2�764ms)
HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7�676]
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@13dbed9e as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@41da3aee.
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Risen-Komputer:8686/jndi/rmi://Risen-Komputer:8686/jmxrmi
```

What can I do to stary my GlassFish on Eclipse Kepler IDE ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with GlassFish tools for Eclipse.

There is an open issue on the GitHub repository for Payara (derived from GlassFish) which applys to Mac OS X and Windows:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/370

The only workaround there currently is to:

> do everything manual (start/stop/deploy GF from command line) and then just attach Eclipse via a remote debugger